# image upload by webcam in php

Tags: php, upload, webcam

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="myname" id="myname">
    <input type="submit" name="send" id="send">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="webcam.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
        document.write( webcam.get_html(320, 240) );
</script>
<form>
        <input type=button value="Configure..." onClick="webcam.configure()">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type=button name="img" value="Take Snapshot" onClick="take_snapshot()">
    </form>

<script language="JavaScript">
        document.write( webcam.get_html(320, 240) );
</script>

<script language="JavaScript">
    webcam.set_api_url( 'test.php' );
        webcam.set_quality( 90 ); // JPEG quality (1 - 100)
        webcam.set_shutter_sound( true ); // play shutter click sound
        webcam.set_hook( 'onComplete', 'my_completion_handler' );

        function take_snapshot(){
            // take snapshot and upload to server

            document.getElementById('upload_results').innerHTML = '<h1>Uploading...</h1>';

            webcam.snap();
        }

        function my_completion_handler(msg) {
            // extract URL out of PHP output
            if (msg.match(/(http\:\/\/\S+)/)) {
                // show JPEG image in page
                document.getElementById('upload_results').innerHTML ='<h1>Upload Successful!</h1>';
                // reset camera for another shot
                webcam.reset();
            }
            else {alert("PHP Error: " + msg);
        }
    </script>
<div id="upload_results" style="background-color:#eee;"></div>
```

I am working in the PHP language. I am trying to upload the image from webcam and want to save it on my PC. Webcam is working fine; it is opening the webcam but I click on the `take_snapshot`, it does nothing.

I'm having a problem in understanding the JavaScript part and what is happening when `take_snapshot` button is clicked.

My webcam.js

```
/* JPEGCam v1.0.9 */
/* Webcam library for capturing JPEG images and submitting to a server */
/* Copyright (c) 2008 - 2009 Joseph Huckaby <jhuckaby@goldcartridge.com> */
/* Licensed under the GNU Lesser Public License */
/* http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html */

/* Usage:
    <script language="JavaScript">
        document.write( webcam.get_html(320, 240) );
        webcam.set_api_url( 'test.php' );
        webcam.set_hook( 'onComplete', 'my_callback_function' );
        function my_callback_function(response) {
            alert("Success! PHP returned: " + response);
        }
    </script>
    <a href="javascript:void(webcam.snap())">Take Snapshot</a>
*/

// Everything is under a 'webcam' Namespace
window.webcam = {
    version: '1.0.9',

    // globals
    ie: !!navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/),
    protocol: location.protocol.match(/https/i) ? 'https' : 'http',
    callback: null, // user callback for completed uploads
    swf_url: 'webcam.swf', // URI to webcam.swf movie (defaults to cwd)
    shutter_url: 'shutter.mp3', // URI to shutter.mp3 sound
    api_url: '', // URL to upload script
    loaded: false, // true when webcam movie finishes loading
    quality: 90, // JPEG quality (1 - 100)
    shutter_sound: true, // shutter sound effect on/off
    stealth: false, // stealth mode (do not freeze image upon capture)
    hooks: {
        onLoad: null,
        onComplete: null,
        onError: null
    }, // callback hook functions

    set_hook: function(name, callback) {
        // set callback hook
        // supported hooks: onLoad, onComplete, onError
        if (typeof(this.hooks[name]) == 'undefined')
            return alert("Hook type not supported: " + name);

        this.hooks[name] = callback;
    },

    fire_hook: function(name, value) {
        // fire hook callback, passing optional value to it
        if (this.hooks[name]) {
            if (typeof(this.hooks[name]) == 'function') {
                // callback is function reference, call directly
                this.hooks[name](value);
            }
            else if (typeof(this.hooks[name]) == 'array') {
                // callback is PHP-style object instance method
                this.hooks[name][0][this.hooks[name][1]](value);
            }
            else if (window[this.hooks[name]]) {
                // callback is global function name
                window[ this.hooks[name] ](value);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false; // no hook defined
    },

    set_api_url: function(url) {
        // set location of upload API script
        this.api_url = url;
    },

    set_swf_url: function(url) {
        // set location of SWF movie (defaults to webcam.swf in cwd)
        this.swf_url = url;
    },

    get_html: function(width, height, server_width, server_height) {
        // Return HTML for embedding webcam capture movie
        // Specify pixel width and height (640x480, 320x240, etc.)
        // Server width and height are optional, and default to movie width/height
        if (!server_width) server_width = width;
        if (!server_height) server_height = height;

        var html = '';
        var flashvars = 'shutter_enabled=' + (this.shutter_sound ? 1 : 0) + 
            '&shutter_url=' + escape(this.shutter_url) + 
            '&width=' + width + 
            '&height=' + height + 
            '&server_width=' + server_width + 
            '&server_height=' + server_height;

        if (this.ie) {
            html += '<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="'+this.protocol+'://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="'+width+'" height="'+height+'" id="webcam_movie" align="middle"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" /><param name="movie" value="'+this.swf_url+'" /><param name="loop" value="false" /><param name="menu" value="false" /><param name="quality" value="best" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" /><param name="flashvars" value="'+flashvars+'"/></object>';
        }
        else {
            html += '<embed id="webcam_movie" src="'+this.swf_url+'" loop="false" menu="false" quality="best" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="'+width+'" height="'+height+'" name="webcam_movie" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="always" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" flashvars="'+flashvars+'" />';
        }

        this.loaded = false;
        return html;
    },

    get_movie: function() {
        // get reference to movie object/embed in DOM
        if (!this.loaded) return alert("ERROR: Movie is not loaded yet");
        var movie = document.getElementById('webcam_movie');
        if (!movie) alert("ERROR: Cannot locate movie 'webcam_movie' in DOM");
        return movie;
    },

    set_stealth: function(stealth) {
        // set or disable stealth mode
        this.stealth = stealth;
    },

    snap: function(url, callback, stealth) {
        // take snapshot and send to server
        // specify fully-qualified URL to server API script
        // and callback function (string or function object)
        if (callback) this.set_hook('onComplete', callback);
        if (url) this.set_api_url(url);
        if (typeof(stealth) != 'undefined') this.set_stealth( stealth );

        this.get_movie()._snap( this.api_url, this.quality, this.shutter_sound ? 1 : 0, this.stealth ? 1 : 0 );
    },

    freeze: function() {
        // freeze webcam image (capture but do not upload)
        this.get_movie()._snap('', this.quality, this.shutter_sound ? 1 : 0, 0 );
    },

    upload: function(url, callback) {
        // upload image to server after taking snapshot
        // specify fully-qualified URL to server API script
        // and callback function (string or function object)
        if (callback) this.set_hook('onComplete', callback);
        if (url) this.set_api_url(url);

        this.get_movie()._upload( this.api_url );
    },

    reset: function() {
        // reset movie after taking snapshot
        this.get_movie()._reset();
    },

    configure: function(panel) {
        // open flash configuration panel -- specify tab name:
        // "camera", "privacy", "default", "localStorage", "microphone", "settingsManager"
        if (!panel) panel = "camera";
        this.get_movie()._configure(panel);
    },

    set_quality: function(new_quality) {
        // set the JPEG quality (1 - 100)
        // default is 90
        this.quality = new_quality;
    },

    set_shutter_sound: function(enabled, url) {
        // enable or disable the shutter sound effect
        // defaults to enabled
        this.shutter_sound = enabled;
        this.shutter_url = url ? url : 'shutter.mp3';
    },

    flash_notify: function(type, msg) {
        // receive notification from flash about event
        switch (type) {
            case 'flashLoadComplete':
                // movie loaded successfully
                this.loaded = true;
                this.fire_hook('onLoad');
                break;

            case 'error':
                // HTTP POST error most likely
                if (!this.fire_hook('onError', msg)) {
                    alert("JPEGCam Flash Error: " + msg);
                }
                break;

            case 'success':
                // upload complete, execute user callback function
                // and pass raw API script results to function
                this.fire_hook('onComplete', msg.toString());
                break;

            default:
                // catch-all, just in case
                alert("jpegcam flash_notify: " + type + ": " + msg);
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What is `webcam.js`? Can you link us that file?

Comment: @Glavić , i have done it

Comment: As I see, you have just copied source code from [working example](http://bowser.effectgames.com/~jhuckaby/jpegcam/stealth.html). If I download http://code.google.com/p/jpegcam/downloads/list and upload `htdocs` folder on my localhost, and run `test.html` via browser it works.

Comment: I know this is 8 years late but this question just popped up on my feed and I think it is very interesting. Have you fixed this bug yet?

Answer (score 0):

In order to run PHP scripts, you must use have a web server set up with PHP.
A common setup is Linux/Apache/MySQL/PHP, otherwise known as [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29). A PHP script without such a setup will not be able to run and will simply display as text in a web browser.

Comment: The problem here has nothing to do with setting up a server. You perfectly can run a php development server. For instance with a command line like `php -S localhost:8080 index.php`.